# multiple layers of closures and synchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures, synchronous

This is an extension to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576279/how-to-synchronously-declare-js-object-and-then-edit-a-property-of-the-object-wi), which received a very explanatory answer. It turns out that I did not provide enough context to my app to make the question useful enough for my actual situation.

Here is a **route** within my Express app:

```
var eventbriteService = require('../apiRequests/eventbriteService');
var queue = require('queue-async');    
app.get('/events', function (req, res, next) {
    queue()
        .defer(eventbriteService.getEventbriteEvents)
        .await(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {return next(err);}    
            console.log("here are the events from routes" ,data);
        });
});
```

This route calls the following **service**:

```
exports.getEventbriteEvents = function (cb) {

    var eventbriteEvents = [];

    request({
        uri: "https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=R3DQQXPXBTSMUWVNOV&city=Austin&date=2014-10-01&2014-10-15",
        method: "GET", timeout: 10000, followRedirect: true, maxRedirects: 10,
    }, function(err, response, body){
        if (err) return cb(err);

        try {
            var eventsJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            var eventsWithAllFields = eventsJSON.events;
            var totalEventsNumber = parseInt(eventsWithAllFields[0].summary.total_items);

            for (var i = 1, l = eventsWithAllFields.length; i < l; i++) {

                var eventObject = {
                    name: eventsWithAllFields[i].event.title,
                    images: []
                };

                var jsdom = require('jsdom');
                var arrayOfImgs = [];
                jsdom.env({
                    html: eventsWithAllFields[i].event.description,
                    scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
                    done: function(evtobj, errors, window) {
                        window.$('img').each(function(){
                            var imgSrc = window.$(this).attr('src');
                            console.log(imgSrc);
                            evtobj.images.push(imgSrc);
                        });
                        eventbriteEvents.push(evtobj);
                    }.bind(null, eventObject)
                });

            }

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(err);
        }

        console.log(eventbriteEvents);
        cb(null, eventbriteEvents);

    });

};
```

This is my **console** output:

```
{}
[]
here are the events from routes []
https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/eventlogos/90039995/about.png
https://evbdn.eventbrite.com/s3-s3/eventlogos/90039995/bluedawntour1.jpg
```

The code is executing in the following order:

1. eventbrite service logs the array of eventbrite objects (empty)
2. route logs array of eventbrite objects (empty)
3. eventbrite service uses jsdom to find the existing imgs in the html

Obviously this is out of sync, and I am quite confused on rectifying this, considering the many layers of callbacks, closures, and queue-async.

I'm using the queue-async library to define a callback in the route which ends up being populated by the eventbrite service. This was working fine until I recently added the jsdom html-parsing functionality. In addition to solving this immediate problem, I am looking for help structuring my mental model of callbacks, closures, and synchronous code.

Comment: Not really an answer but checkout https://github.com/FuturesJS/FuturesJS
its really helpful to handle handle complex callback hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling your callback when your `for` loop is finished, but the `for` loop is calling an asynchronous function (`jsdom.env`) on each pass of its loop. What ends up happening is the `for` loop finishes looping before the functions it calls are complete.

What you need is something that will call a callback when all those asynchronous functions are complete. Since you're already using `queue-async` elsewhere, let's just use that *(see comments in modified code)*:

```
var queue = require('queue-async');

exports.getEventbriteEvents = function (cb) {
    request({
        uri: "https://www.eventbrite.com/json/event_search?app_key=<redacted>&city=Austin&date=2014-10-01&2014-10-15",
        method: "GET", timeout: 10000, followRedirect: true, maxRedirects: 10,
    }, function(err, response, body){
        if (err) return cb(err);

        try {
            var jsdomQueue = queue();
            var eventsJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            var eventsWithAllFields = eventsJSON.events;
            var totalEventsNumber = parseInt(eventsWithAllFields[0].summary.total_items);

            for (var i = 1, l = eventsWithAllFields.length; i < l; i++) {

                var eventObject = {
                    name: eventsWithAllFields[i].event.title,
                    images: []
                };

                var jsdom = require('jsdom');

                // push ("defer") the jsdom.env async function on to the jsdomQueue
                // note: we have to move the .bind for that to still work
                jsdomQueue.defer(function(i, evtobj, deferCallback) {
                    jsdom.env({
                        html: eventsWithAllFields[i].event.description,
                        scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
                        done: function(errors, window) {
                            window.$('img').each(function(){
                                var imgSrc = window.$(this).attr('src');
                                console.log(imgSrc);
                                evtobj.images.push(imgSrc);
                            });

                            // call the deferCallback with the evtobj
                            deferCallback(null, evtobj);
                        }
                    });
                }.bind(null, i, eventObject));

            }

            // wait for all the previously deferred functions to finish.
            // the objects passed to deferCallback above will be in the
            // eventbriteEvents array.
            jsdomQueue.awaitAll(function(err, eventbriteEvents) {
                if (err) {
                    // any additional error handling
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    // now you can call your callback
                    console.log(eventbriteEvents);
                    cb(null, eventbriteEvents);
                }
            });

        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return cb(err);
        }

    });

};
```

Comment: I'm not getting any output at all. It seems like execution never returns to the queue-async in the routes file, because i never even get the hard-coded "here are the events from routes" logged.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a variable (`i`) that needed to be bound when I moved that `.bind` call (I've edited the answer).

Comment: still nothing. what would be causing it to not return control to the route?

Comment: Hmm, well, that would happen if your callback `cb` is never called.  It sounds like the callback in `jsdomQueue.awaitAll` isn't getting called for some reason.

Comment: Oh, did you notice that I changed your `app_key` in `request`s `uri` parameter? (I figured you might not want that posted everywhere. sorry, I should have mentioned that)

Comment: haha thank you for changing the key... But I didn't copy your code verbatim, I left the key in my code.